# Is it possible to inject into the main controller and have it be available to other controllers? Ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

for example, app.controller is my main controller.

```
app.controller('appController', ['$scope','$ionicNavBarDelegate', function ($scope,$ionicNavBarDelegate) {
}]);
```

and my second controller is :

```
app.controller('loginPage', ['$scope','$ionicNavBarDelegate', function ($scope,$ionicNavBarDelegate) {
}]);
```

Can i pass $scope in the main controller and have it be passed along to the loginPage controller without typing it out again in the loginPage controller?

Comment: No, each controller is individually defined and must include the injected items in the controller definition.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can pass data from one controller to other using

```html
$rootScope
```

For

```js
app.controller('loginPage', ['$rootScope','$scope','$ionicNavBarDelegate', function ($rootScope,$scope,$ionicNavBarDelegate) {
  
  $rootScope.Items = "rootscope varibale";
}]);

app.controller('appController', ['$rootScope','$scope','$ionicNavBarDelegate', function ($rootScope,$scope,$ionicNavBarDelegate) {
console.log($rootScope.Items);
}]);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use $rootScope instead of $scope.